# How much would Facebook-only signin limit my user base?

Tags: login, facebook

On my website, I currently have a general register and login with a Facebook login as an option. The problem I have noticed is that I have more spammy users creating fake usernames and uploading non-relevant content with general registration as opposed to the Facebook users.

So I'm considering abandoning general registration and have Facebook-only sign-in with intent to add Twitter, Google+, etc, but I'm concerned this will impact/restrict my user base. Are there any references that determine what percentage of users sign up with general, Facebook, Twitter, Google+ logins and would I jeopardize my growth potential by removing general login?

Comment: I'm not sure if this regards UX (maybe it does to some extent, but is mostly more about databases and general learnings from projects). One of the disadvantages I know is, however, a possibility to loose connection between user in your database and Facebook user if the FB account is deleted.

Comment: Thanks Dominik. I believe this is clearly a UX question. Users that dont have a Facebook account could have a bad experience as they may want to contribute content, but cannot. Good point about the lost connection - my solution to this would be to retain the username, but replace the user's profile image with a silhouette avatar.

Comment: From this pint of view, yes, this is a limitation. However, you can use FB/G+ login as an option, linked to the user account, so that he/she can use either manually entered credentials or their FB/G+ login. Moreover, you can pull data from the FB or other account while registering, so that the newly created user account data is more adequate. We use it even here, on UX.SE.

Comment: Just don't make it the only option. Not everybody likes to mix different aspects of their lives with what they do on facebook.